# for loop with OR logical operator not acting as I expect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wanting to loop through a list to check whether its elements are NOT equal to something. Code below...

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for item in board:
        if item != 'X' or item != 'O':
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

No matter what list a pass through the function, it always outputs false. 
However, if I change the if statement to only consider one of the conditions, it successfully checks for that condition.

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for item in board:
        if item != 'X':
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return `True` if every element in `item` is valid. You shouldn't be using `or` there, you should be using `and`.

It'd be easier to compare against a string and use the `in` for membership testing. You can also use `all` to do this more concisely.

```
for item in board:
    return all(x in 'XO' for x in item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical problem. I recommend you study a bit of logic to fully understand logical statements in programming. There is no letter that can be different to X or O. If you evaluate X, that letter is different from O so the output is False and the same goes for X. In a more a mathematical language, the subset you are evaluating is void.

If you want to evaluate that each element is not X or O.

```
    if item == 'X' or item == 'O':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I hope this helps